# Function object, "length property"

Tags: javascript

Please, explain to me how this function run? I can't understand the order of flow and why in positive answer there is two functions?

```js
function ask(question, ...handlers) {
  let isYes = confirm(question);

  for(let handler of handlers) {
    if (handler.length == 0) {
      if (isYes) handler();
    } else {
      handler(isYes);
    }
  }

}

// for positive answer, both handlers are called
// for negative answer, only the second one
ask("Question?", () => alert('You said yes'), result => alert(result));
```

Comment: console.log() is your friend, use it to figure out what things are.

Comment: What, precisely, don't you understand? There are a lot of basic concepts in this code (and a few advanced ones). The order of flow is very straight forward.

Comment: [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length): _"The `length` property indicates the number of parameters expected by the function"_

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)? It says it clearly in the first sentence: *"The `length` property indicates the number of parameters expected by the function."*

Comment: @ axiac Oh, my god! Why is there always someone who think that if he understand something, then everyone else should? Of course I've read this documentation, where on Earth do you think I get this example???

Comment: The proper way to ask, when having read the documentation, is mentioning this, and why the related documentation did not help. A general "i don't understand at all", and no mentions of what has been read/attempted, is not useful. Complaining about this in a sarcastic way doesn't change that, nor help the situation.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I pointed what exactly I don't understand : why in positive answer there is two functions?

Comment: There are not two functions in what i can only best guess you define as "positive answer". I see one function declaration, which contains three calls, at least in code. There is also another call below, which defines two arrow functions, but i assume that's just part of the test code, from whatever code challenge website you use.

Comment: @ ASDFGerte No, it's whole code, from here [link](https://javascript.info/function-object#the-length-property)

Comment: See, that link is a good example for "no mentions of what has been read/attempted" - it would have been useful to add that to the question, and people could have seen, that a simple link to the MDN probably won't solve your issue. It would also give context to the above code. Also, i still don't understand, what you are asking. What do you mean by "there [are] two functions?"

Comment: @Roman the page you linked to already includes an explanation of HOW that function runs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with your function call:

```js
ask("Question?", () => alert('You said yes'), result => alert(result));
```

**You have 2 "handlers":**

1. `alert('You said yes')`: This one is just a simple alert, no parameters
2. `result => alert(result)`: This one takes one parameter (result) and passes it to alert

**So, now let's look at the `ask` function. It has 2 parameters:**

1. `question`: Question being asked, passed to the `confirm` function, which is not supplied in your code
2. `...handlers`: Takes all handlers passed to it as an array

**Algorithm:**

So, our 2 handlers above go into an array, which we iterate over. We check their `length` property to determine if it is `0`. If it is 0, we then check if `isYes` is true. Otherwise, we call the handler and pass the value of `isYes`.

- **if `handler.length == 0`** (we have no parameters) **AND if `isYes === true`**: We call the handler without passing anything to it
- **else**: We call the handler and provide the value of `isYes`

So, when `confirm` returns `true`, because our first handler `alert('You said yes')` has no parameters, we then check the 2nd if-statement. This leads us to call that function. So the user sees `You said yes`. The second handler is iterated over, it has a length of `1`, so we go to the `else` statement and call it by passing the value of `isYes`. This displays a 2nd alert that has the value of `isYes`.

Comment: Thank you!!! For the most for your patience and not pointing to my stupidness. Now I totally get the mechanism of running this function. It's very clear and intelligibly, exactly for such slow-witted person as me).

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself, it took me some debugging in dev tools to figure out what was going on :) we all start somewhere! I think that debugging is easily one of the most important skills that a developer can learn, and can also be one of the most difficult.

Comment: @ Evan Bechtol  Could you suggest maybe some resourses for learning this debugging issue? I've heard it a lot about importance of this skill, but can't find where it can be mastered.

Comment: @Roman I think that [Flavio Copes](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-debugging/) wrote a great article about how to debug. Also, you should check [youtube - how to debug javascript](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+debug+javascript), some awesome videos there!